# Silverlight 4 Support in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2013

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 and tried to open a project which contained Silverlight 4 projects. In the migration however, the Silverlight target version was changed to 5 and is not not editable in the project settings. There are too many issues with upgrading the project to Silverlight 5 and we're working on converting the Silverlight projects to MVC web apps.

Has anyone had success or have a solution for working with Silverlight 4 projects in Visual Studio 2013 without changing the Silverlight version to 5?

Comment: I have the same problem. For now I will go back to using VS 2012.

Comment: That's what we've ended up doing too. Just use VS 2012 for the silverlight stuff.

Comment: This affects one of our Windows Phone projects too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Silverlight 4 is not supported. The list of [supported frameworks and targeting packs for Visual Studio 2013 can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn250998.aspx).

**Silverlight**

```
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| Target Platform     | Targeting pack download        |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| Silverlight 5       | Included in Visual Studio 2013 |
|                     | Runtime installer:             |
|                     | Silverlight 5 Runtime          | 
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
```

For Silverlight 4 and below you'll need to use the older version of Visual Studio or upgrade your project. Officially Silverlight 4 is also no longer supported on older versions of visual Studio though, the primary reason for this is that [Silverlight 4 has reached the end of its support lifecycle](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/blagunas/archive/2013/10/15/silverlight-4-maintsream-support-has-ended.aspx).

[Official overview can be found here](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&c2=12905).

### Silverlight 4

**Lifecycle Start Date**: 4/15/2010

**Mainstream Support End Date**: *1/8/2013*

**Extended Support End Date**: Review Note

**Notes**: Support for releases known as Tools ends no less than 12 months following the notification date. Customers are encouraged to promptly update to a later release to continue to receive support, including security updates.